# Fixing leaky drain gasket

Tags: drain, sink, pvc

I am having some trouble making my sink drain gasket not leak. I have a very old sink (50+ years) and it is made of iron. The overflow drain holes in the drain pipe have over the years corroded part of the sink so now water is getting out of the overflow hole, outside of the drain pipe, and building up behind the gasket. Here is a picture of the issue.[image]

As you can see there is a bead of water. Yes the nut is on tight. Until I get a replacement sink, is there some way I can stop this dripping? Perhaps silicon caulking? Thank you.

Comment: I see you accepted teh answer, were you able to clean it up or seat it securely?

Comment: @nobyman Well the solution to my problem is to get a new drop in sink because the darn sink is just too old. My caulking worked but it is only temporary. I can also get a drain pipe without overflow holes but at this point just getting a new drop is the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a honer and it is not rusted through and through, you could clean up the outer lip, remove any calcium buildup, and ensure the outer lip of the sink itself is solid.

Also make sure it is not bent (the sink) and ideally, the drain tube is also perpendicular to the base of the sink. Make sure the sink is still sitting level on the counter top.

if everything is level, flush, and clean, you should be all set.

If the drain area of the sink is rusted through, you'll have to replace it, or epoxy it like mad. (then clean it, and seat everything).

Comment: In case anyone cares to know, the final solution to this issue was to replace the old sink with a new one. I spent the 35 dollars and everything is as good as new.